# Hide some MySite social features

Tags: 2010, javascript, feature, my-site, social

I'm new at SharePoint 2010, and I'd like to implement social features. I used MySite, but there are too much possibilities, and I would like to hide (or disabled) some of them (red-cicled in the picture below) :
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/209/socialn.png/

Do someone knows how to achieve this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://kjellsj.blogspot.in/2010/06/customizing-sharepoint-2010-my-sites.html

check the above link it help to enable and disable web parts and you can customize my site.

Comment: Thank you, your link helped me a lot, I didn't find it.